# ApiService should be created: R3InjectorError DynamicTestModule ApiService HttpClient NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpHandler! Angular 17.0.6

Tags: angular

I am getting the following error when running my tests using `ng test` in Angular. I have read similar questions but I don't think it is the same problems given that I tried the solutions in the answers with no luck.

```
ApiService > should be created
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)
[ApiService -> HttpClient -> HttpHandler -> HttpHandler]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpHandler!
error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath:
[ 'ApiService', 'HttpClient', 'HttpHandler', 'HttpHandler' ] })
```

Here is my code:

```
  import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
  import { ApiService } from './api.service';
  import { EnvServiceProvider } from './env.service.provider';
  import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

  describe('ApiService', () => {
    let service: ApiService;

    beforeEach(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [ApiService, EnvServiceProvider, HttpClient]
      });
      service = TestBed.inject(ApiService);
    });

    it('should be created', () => {
      expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `provideHttpClient()` instead of just providing the `HttpClient`.

`provideHttpClient()` will define the providers for `HttpClient`, `HttpHandler`, `HttpBackend`, the interceptors etc.

```
  import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
  import { ApiService } from './api.service';
  import { EnvServiceProvider } from './env.service.provider';
  //import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
  import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

  describe('ApiService', () => {
    let service: ApiService;

    beforeEach(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [ApiService, EnvServiceProvider, provideHttpClient()]
      });
      service = TestBed.inject(ApiService);
    });

    it('should be created', () => {
      expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
```